# Viewing code and html page content

Tags: php, html

I'm looking for a way where you can write something normal text, ie content / problem for snakes code, for example in [div]  [/ div] code could stand without problems where it does not appear or anything,

Therefore I search for a way to make that I can make normal html text but contemporaries do some code if you have problem

right moment, I use tiny mce to make some text, but when I should have known it since I do like this,

```
<?php echo strip_tags($tekst);?>
```

how come it appears on the page:

```
<?php echo \"Hello\";?>
```

what I want is just here on this page about writing some text and some code to the problem or the like, I'm thinking if I can fix it the same way or look like?

Comment: You probably have magic quotes turned on.

Comment: @Brad How to check if I have it? and how do I use it?

Comment: what should I look for?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php